# Type error in models.py - 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-models

After data migration I want to assign settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL user.username to author field.

```
@property
def author(self):
    return self.user.username() #'line-17'
```

getting:

> TypeError at /posts/  (homepage)
>   'str' object is not callable

models.py in author, line 17

Comment: Yes. Why are you calling it? Remove those parentheses.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the parentheses is beacause its inside a class

Comment: Er, what? That makes no sense. As the error says, `username` is a string. It's not a method. Don't call it. Just do `return self.user.username`.

Comment: oh thanks. that was stupid of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
@property
def author(self):
    return self.user.username
```

username is a string and should not be called as a method like `example_method()`.

Answer (score 0):

As `username` is a string inside a class, so you do not have to use parenthesis:-

```
@property
def author(self):
    return self.user.username    #'line-17'
```

If `username` is a function inside a class then you have to use parenthesis:-

```
 @property
 def author(self):
     return self.user.username()   # If username is a function.
```

OR you can check by `callable` whether username is function or not:-

```
callable(self.user.username)
```

It will return `True` OR `False`, `True` means `username` is a function.